# Reading multiple csv lines into single row in R

Tags: r, csv, subset, reshape, rbind

I have a csv file with multiple rows per unique id that I need to format into a single row of a dataframe.  After reading in this file, I end up with an initial dataframe:

```
id  week   v1  v2
01  week1  3   2
01  week2  5   2
01  week3  2   3
02  week1  1   2
02  week2  5   5
03  week1  4   1
03  week2  4   3
03  week3  4   2
[etc...]
```

I want pull all the instances of v1 for a given id, so I grab all the unique id

```
uniqid<-unique(data$id)
```

and then iterate over these from 1:length(uniqid)

```
temp <- subset(data,data$id==uniqid[i])
```

and pull each week data into a temp variable

```
week1 <- temp$v1[temp$week=="week1]
```

so I can reform the dataframe using rbind

```
output <- rbind(output,data.frame(ID=uniqid[i],week1,week2,week3))
```

My problem is, for example with id=02, there is no week3, so the rbind breaks.  It appears the week3 variable is never created; it doesn't show as NA.  How can I test to see if the variable was created and set it to NA (or 0) so the rbind won't fail?  Or is there a completely different/more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recast` function from reshape2 package.

```
DF
##   id  week v1 v2
## 1  1 week1  3  2
## 2  1 week2  5  2
## 3  1 week3  2  3
## 4  2 week1  1  2
## 5  2 week2  5  5
## 6  3 week1  4  1
## 7  3 week2  4  3
## 8  3 week3  4  2


require(reshape2)
temp <- recast(DF, id ~ week, measure.var = "v1")
result <- temp$data
row.names(result) <- temp$labels[[1]]$id
colnames(result) <- temp$labels[[2]]$week
result
##   week1 week2 week3
## 1     3     5     2
## 2     1     5    NA
## 3     4     4     4
```

or as @AnandaMahto suggested, just use `dcast`

```
dcast(DF, id ~ week, value.var = "v1")
##   id week1 week2 week3
## 1  1     3     5     2
## 2  2     1     5    NA
## 3  3     4     4     4
```

Comment: Why `recast` and not the more commonly used `dcast`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto because I learnt `recast` first ;).. and it doesn't need `melt`ing data first.

Comment: I still don't follow your logic. This dataset is already long (no need to `melt`) and using `dcast` instead of `recast` will solve the problem without jumping through hoops of renaming things: `dcast(DF, id ~ week, value.var="v1")`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `reshape`:

```
> reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar="id", timevar="week")
  id v1.week1 v2.week1 v1.week2 v2.week2 v1.week3 v2.week3
1  1        3        2        5        2        2        3
4  2        1        2        5        5       NA       NA
6  3        4        1        4        3        4        2
```

If you want to drop the "v2" column from the output, you can do that before you reshape the data, or you can drop it from within the function.

```
> reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar="id", timevar="week", drop="v2")
  id v1.week1 v1.week2 v1.week3
1  1        3        5        2
4  2        1        5       NA
6  3        4        4        4
```